# Vagrant up fails with VERR_ACCESS_DENIED error

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to learn Vagrant but facing an issue at the beginning of my way.. I was googling for a while but didn't find useful answer.

Setup details: Windows 10 Vagrant 2.1.5 VirtualBox 5.2.18 r124319

Problem description:

While running "vagrant up" command I get following error:

> PS C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\desktop\vagrant_test> vagrant up Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider... ==>
>   default: Importing base box 'geerlingguy/centos7'... There was an
>   error while executing VBoxManage, a CLI used by Vagrant for
>   controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["import", "\?\C:\HashiCorp;\boxes\geerlingguy-VAGRANTSLASH-centos7\1.2.10\virtualbox
>   \box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname",
>   "packer-centos-7-x86_64_1539008587672_41094", "--vsys", "0", "--
>   unit", "8", "--disk", "C:\Users\Micha\u2502\VirtualBox
>   VMs\packer-centos-7-x86_64_1539008587672_41094
>   \packer-centos-7-x86_64-disk001.vmdk"]
>
> Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
>   Interpreting
>   \?\C:\HashiCorp;\boxes\geerlingguy-VAGRANTSLASH-centos7\1.2.10\virtualbox\box.ovf...
>   OK. 0%... Progress state: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR VBoxManage.exe: error:
>   Appliance import failed VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the
>   directory 'C:\Users\MichaÔöé\VirtualBox
>   VMs\packer-centos->7-x86_64_1539008587672_41094' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005),
>   component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance VBoxManage.exe: error:
>   Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct
>   HandlerArg *)" at line 886 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp

For some reason VBoxManage.exe tool is not able to access the directory where my VirtualBox VMs are stored.

> VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the directory
>   'C:\Users\MichaÔöé\VirtualBox
>   VMs\packer-centos-7-x86_64_1539008587672_41094' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Username contains one Polish letter "ł" that's why we see in the path:

> C:\Users\MichaÔöé\VirtualBox VMs

But I don't think it is a problem.

This is default installation so I would expect it to be running.

BR

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, running PowerShell console as administrator resolved the issue.